# The format of file in terminal

Tags: files, format

How do we know the format of a file directly in terminal? Could somebody give me some advice?

Comment: What do you mean by format?

Comment: Try `file FILENAME`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most common:**

```
$ file mediafile.mkv
mediafile.mkv: Matroska data

$ file ~/.bashrc
/home/users/l/j/ljames/.bashrc: ASCII text

$ file /usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/passwd: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=84a7c6f14ce2ce87570911abd85e19ea45b6754b, stripped

$ file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/java

$ file /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java: symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

$ file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, BuildID[sha1]=c90f19ee0af98c47ccaa7181853cfd14867bc931, not stripped
```

**For media, you can get more details of the format with these command variations:**

```
$ identify ~/.bashrc
identify-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.

$ mediainfo mediafile.mkv 
General
Unique ID                                : 158129335275244501904084975368798538245 (0x76F69A29135BD58AE99798A804250A05)
Complete name                            : mediafile.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 64.9 MiB
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101
Writing library                          : Lavf56.40.101 / Lavf56.40.101
IsTruncated                              : Yes

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2643 5c65704
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=123 / keyint_min=20 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=22.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : A_AC3
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 fps (1536 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -367ms
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

$ file image.png
image.png: PNG image data, 382 x 279, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

$ identify image.png
image.png PNG 382x279 382x279+0+0 8-bit sRGB 52.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000

$ mediainfo image.png
General
Complete name                            : image.png
Format                                   : PNG
Format/Info                              : Portable Network Graphic
File size                                : 51.0 KiB

Image
Format                                   : PNG
Format/Info                              : Portable Network Graphic
Width                                    : 382 pixels
Height                                   : 279 pixels
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Stream size                              : 51.0 KiB (100%)
```

**Note:**

The **identify** command may take a long time to analize a media file before it outputs.  The output details may also fill numerous screens.

**Update**

I listed some very common tools for checking the file information and formats.  A very common tool from the repository is **exiftool**.  It'll provide very comprehensive details of the format of media files.

Comment: `exiftool image.jpg` would give you exif information of a foto.

Comment: @RoVo I debated on how many tools to include in the answer.  I use exiftool all the time.  I didn't include exiftool because I recall having to install it to use it.  I just checked and find that **mediainfo** also has to be installed from the repository just like my favorite, **exiftool**.  I'll add this as a note to the answer.

Comment: The answers are so great and quiet useful!! Thanks